# How to return a boolean from a async function?

Tags: ionic-framework, async-await, promise

Sorry for my question which is probably simple but I didn't find the solution of my problem. I need to get one information from Firebase and the below function works well -> I've the console loging empty or not empty accordingly to the situation but I don't find a way to obtain the results elsewhere. It's probably cause I don't know how to use a Promise but ... I don't find the correct way to retrieve the boolean. Here is the function :

```
async checkIfCreatorUuidHasGameUuid(creatorUuid: string, showModeration: boolean, gameUuid : string): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
        let snap: firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
        if (showModeration) {
            snap = await this.firestoreService.db.collection('announces').where('creatorUuid', '==', creatorUuid).where('gameUuid', '==', gameUuid).get();
        } else {
            snap = await this.firestoreService.db.collection('announces')
                .where('creatorUuid', '==', creatorUuid).where('inModeration', '==', false).where('gameUuid', '==', gameUuid).get();
        }

        if(snap.empty){
            console.log("empty")
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log("not empty")
            return true;
    }

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Here is the call to this function :

```
if (this.announceService.checkIfCreatorUuidHasGameUuid(activeUser.uuid, true, this.game.uuid)) {
            console.log("true")
        }
```

It always log true and the promise returned by my previous function is always the same wether it's logging "empty" or "not empty" in the function above. What did I do wrong ? The function and the call to the function are in two separates pages for information
Thanks

Comment: `if (await this.announceService.checkIfCreatorUuidHasGameUuid`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks ! It worked (and I knew I was missing something easy... Thank for your help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always logging true because you are calling the async function without **await**ing for the response.

That's why you will always receive true, if you want the correct value for the **Promise< boolean >** return, just do:

```
if (await this.announceService.checkIfCreatorUuidHasGameUuid(activeUser.uuid, true, this.game.uuid)) {
   console.log("true")
}
```